# Combining two CSS effects

Tags: html, css

Under a image bock I am looking to insert a slider in the middle taking just 30% of space in the exact centre.

Here I am hoping to have 1 out of the 6 images (logo) previewed `in_out`. At the same time, I am running a flickering effect `flicker`. I am awfully close but for some reason at the start all logos appear and I can't get them to work correctly.

I have been following Number 3 in this [tutorial](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/)

HTML:

```css
.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  -webkit-animation: flicker 20s linear infinite both;
          animation: flicker 2s linear infinite both;        
}

@-webkit-keyframes in_out {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

.shadow img:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 30s;
}
.shadow img:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 24s;
}
.shadow img:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 18s;
}
.shadow img:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 12;
}
.shadow img:nth-of-type(5) {
  animation-delay: 6;
}
.shadow img:nth-of-type(6) {
  animation-delay: 0;
}

.shadow img {
  width: 250px;
  margin:14em;
  transform: translate(200px, -700px);
  margin-left: 250px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;

  animation-name: in_out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
 <div class="slider"> 
            <img src="components/img/Rectangle.png" class="boxblack">
            <div id="cf" class ="shadow">
              <img src="https://www.antoniomar.co/components/img/logos/1.png">
              <img src="https://www.antoniomar.co/components/img/logos/2.png">
              <img src="https://www.antoniomar.co/components/img/logos/3.png">
              <img src="https://www.antoniomar.co/components/img/logos/4.png">
              <img src="https://www.antoniomar.co/components/img/logos/5.png">
              <img src="https://www.antoniomar.co/components/img/logos/6.png">
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Some of your `animation-delay` values are missing the `s` unit property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent from default showing all images. you must set `opacity` to `zero`. and the time of animation and delay must be fit together. see snippet

```css
.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  -webkit-animation: flicker 20s linear infinite both;
          animation: flicker 2s linear infinite both;        
}

@-webkit-keyframes in_out {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

.shadow img:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 30s;
}
.shadow img:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 24s;
}
.shadow img:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 18s;
}
.shadow img:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
.shadow img:nth-of-type(5) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.shadow img:nth-of-type(6) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.shadow img {
  width: 250px;
  margin:14em;
  transform: translate(200px, -700px);
  margin-left: 250px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 6s ease-in-out;

  animation-name: in_out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider"> 
            <img src="https://www.antoniomar.co/components/img/Rectangle.png" class="boxblack">
            <div id="cf" class ="shadow">
              <img src="https://www.antoniomar.co/components/img/logos/1.png">
              <img src="https://www.antoniomar.co/components/img/logos/2.png">
              <img src="https://www.antoniomar.co/components/img/logos/3.png">
              <img src="https://www.antoniomar.co/components/img/logos/4.png">
              <img src="https://www.antoniomar.co/components/img/logos/5.png">
              <img src="https://www.antoniomar.co/components/img/logos/6.png">
            </div>
          </div>
```